# selenium IDE user extension

Tags: javascript, selenium, generator, selenium-ide

I have a problem with selenium IDE when adding user extension. Code generates random emails correctly when in html but selenium seems not to concatenate "@mail.com" to generated string

In selenium:
    randomString||8|mail||varName

Code I'm using is here:http://seleniumide.blogspot.com/2010/12/random-number-generator.html

And this is what I added:

```
function generateRandomMail( length, chars ) {
var string = '';
for ( var i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ )
    string += chars[ Math.floor( Math.random() * chars.length ) ];
string = string+"@mail.com";
return string;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be probably error in this line:

```
var string = string+"@mail.com";
```

I am not javascript expert, but it seems to me, that you are initializing that variable again. Try delete the `var` at beginning at this line

Comment: Nope - problem seems to be somewhere in selenium

Comment: Can you post me the way how you do it? So I could try to reproduce it... (simple selenium IDE steps to try to write the mail say to search input here in SO)

Answer (score 0):

Generate random Email

Use My code for generate random Email, It work correctly for me.

```
           Selenium.prototype.doTypeRandomEmail = function(locator) {
/**
* Sets the value of an input field to a random email id, 
* as though you typed it in.
*
* @param locator an <a href="#locators">element locator</a>
*/

// All locator-strategies are automatically handled by "findElement"
var element = this.page().findElement(locator);

/* The following block generates a random email string */
var allowedChars = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var stringLength = 8;
var randomstring = '';

for (var i=0; i<stringLength; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedChars.length);
    randomstring += allowedChars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
}

// Append a domain name
randomstring += "@somedomain.com"

// Replace the element text with the new text
this.browserbot.replaceText(element, randomstring);
 };
```

typeRandomEmail || id=wmd-input ||